# Pascals triangle advantages

Tags: geometry, combinations, computational-geometry, pascals-triangle

Pascal triangle can be used to calculate number of combinations using the recursion formula below:-

```
(n k) = (n-1 k-1) + (n-1 k)
```

This can be used in place of formal expansion of (n k) to calculate number of combinations.
But both perform in O(n) time.What are the advantages of using Pascal's triangle method?

Comment: Computing Pascal's triangle is done in O(N^2), not O(N) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage lies in the fact that you can pre-compute all `(ni ki)` where `ni < n` and `ki <= k` in `O(n^2)` time.

So if you have a problem where you may need to query different values in a Pascal triangle, using the recursion formula method and storing all sub-results will mean your preprocessing time is `O(n^2)` but your queries are `O(1)`.

On the other hand, using the formula for `(n k)` in the same application would mean each query is `O(n)` which is inferior to the former approach if you expect more than `n` queries.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are right of course. Fixed. The idea of using it in a preprocessing stage is still is the same though.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compute all `(n k)` for `n<=N` and `0<=k<=N`, Pascal's triangle is very attractive because it just involves one addition per element.

But if you only need the values for a fixed `N`, then it can be advantageous to use this other recursion:

```
(n k) = (n k-1).(n+1-k)/k
```